# python + selenium + chromeでHTMLを読み込みたい

Tags: google-chrome, python3, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

https://www.coin-laundry.co.jp/userp/shop_detail/10000543.html
上記サイトから稼働状況のテーブルを抜き出したいと考えています。

テーブル部分がjavascriptで生成されているようなので、headlessブラウザ（Chrome)をseleniumから操作して取得しようとコードを書いてみました。

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-desktop-notifications')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--lang=ja')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1200x600')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

# URLを開く
TARGET = 'https://www.coin-laundry.co.jp/userp/shop_detail/10000543.html'

driver.get(TARGET)

time.sleep(2)  # とりあえず適当に2秒待つ。

page_source = driver.page_source
html = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
print(html)

driver.quit()  # ブラウザーを終了する。
```

このコードを実行すると、最初に書いたサイトに限り

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

としか返ってきません。
javascriptをレンダリングする前のHTMLも取得できません。
time.sleep()の時間も色々変えてみましたが、結果は同じ。
TARGETの部分を他のURLにした場合は、ちゃんとHTMLコードが出力されます。

selenium + Phantomjs2.1.1 や casperjs + Phantomjs2.1.1も試してみましたが、結果は同様でうまく取得できませんでした。

実行環境は
サーバ AWS EC2
OS Ubuntu 16.04
Python 3.5.2
selenium
Google Chrome 60.0.3112.90
BeautifulSoup4
node 8.2.1

最初はPhantomjsを使ってやっていたのですが、上記サイトだけどうしても取得できませんでした。ブラウザの問題かと思い、リモートデスクトップでUbuntu上のChromeでアクセスしたところ、普通に表示ました。なのでChromeのHeadlessモードなら通常モードと同じように取得できると思ったのですが・・・。

八方塞がりで途方に暮れている次第です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

https接続に失敗していないでしょうか。
Seleniumで動かす前に、まずその環境のブラウザーと、Seleniumの実行ユーザーで、本当にエラー無く対象のページにアクセスできているか確認してみましょう。

> リモートデスクトップでUbuntu上のChromeでアクセスしたところ、普通に表示ました。

おそらくここに見落としがあります。
件のサイトへのアクセス時には中間CA証明書が必要になりますが、これがUbuntuにインストールされていないので、httpsでの接続が失敗しているはずです。
対応する中間CA証明書を、Linux版Chromiumでの管理手順にしたがいインストールしましょう。
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/linux_cert_management.md

Answer (score 0):

Headless Chromeを簡単に操作できるGoogle純正のNodeライブラリ「Puppeteer」が公開されています。それのPython移植版が「[pyppeteer](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer)」です。Seleniumを使うよりもかなり使いやすいと思います。

インストールは、pipでインストールできます。

```
python3 -m pip install pyppeteer
```

Chromium (~100MB)の方は、事前にインストールする必要はなく、実際にプログラムが動作するときに自動的にダウンロードされてインストールされます。

pyppeteerを使うとhtmlの取得は以下のようなコードでできています。このケースでも使えるのではないかと思います。Google Chromeのインストールの必要がないので、サーバ環境でも使いやすいと思います。

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch


async def main():
    TARGET = 'example.com'
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(TARGET)
    # スクリーンショットの取得
    await page.screenshot({'path': 'example.png'})

    html = await page.content()
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```